# dynamically adding controls in tablelayout panel

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have tablelayout panel with 6rows and 6 column
in first cell ie 0,0 I want to add picturebox and in 0,1 I  want add labels by using for loop howvto add picturebox and label alternatively or one below the other like
pb label
pb label

plz help me
all are dynamically I am not getting how to give the cordinates for placing control

Comment: Pictureboxes and labels exist or are you dynamically create them?

Comment: Already exist jst I want to pass name of control and its cordinate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Control)
Dim col, row, i As Integer

list.Add(pb1)
list.Add(lb1)
list.Add(pb2)
list.Add(lb2)
(....)
list.Add(pb6)
list.Add(lb6)

For row = 0 To 5
    For col = 0 To 5
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(list(i), row, col)

        i += 1
    Next
Next
```

valter